# GitHub dark theme flashes in site changes

Tags: github

When I am using GitHub's Dark mode in Safari Version 14.0; while I click github link inside an github page,
or jump around the code files, right before the new site opens, it flashes white and get back to dark mode (which kind of hurts my eye). It does not always happen but happens most of the time.

=> Is there any way to fix this issue?

Example screen recording:

[image]

---

Please note that https://darkreader.org is added as plugin but its not enabled, but I experience the same issue on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out the cache. This should do the trick.

Else its most likely because the dark mode is currently still in beta therefore there may be some issues that persist with the dark mode.

Comment: I have cleaned the cached but still experiencing the same problem :-(

Comment: Most likely its because dark mode is still in beta.

Comment: But I observe the same behavior with https://darkreader.org for GitHub sites

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce that. Likely some browser extension interferes with the rendering. Disable all of them and enable them again, one by one, and see if something changed on each one enabled. This may be a Safari-specific issue, but Chrome (which I've used) has the same rendering engine.